# How to check if element is been dragging with Dojo

Tags: dojo, drag

What to check if an element is been dragging to make a report of how many times has been dragged, any idea? with dojo of course.

This is the element to be sensed.

```
<p id="id_number" class="button">Button_name</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please be more clear. I suppose you mean you want to use `dojo/dnd/Moveable` on your DOM node to make it draggeable? If you look at the [API documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojo/dnd/Moveable#1_9dojo_dnd_Moveable_onDragDetected) you will notice that it has an event called `onDragDetected` which will be useful to you. Just increment a counter with it and you're done.